# AngularJS- testing with Protractor: how to test mouseover function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, submenu, mouseenter

I recently started looking into integrating Protractor into an AngularJS app that I am working on, to write up some automated test scripts that could be run every time a new version of the software is released. I have not used automated testing much before, so am still quite new to it, and learning how to use it.

I have my `conf.js` & `spec.js` files in the following location with my project structure:

repositories/project/app/myApp/frontend/testing

The `conf.js` file has the script:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    multiCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
}
```

and I am starting to write the tests that I'm doing to want to run in the `spec.js` file. The test I am currently writing, is one to test that the appropriate 'sub menu' is displayed when the cursor hovers over one of the menu buttons.

My `spec.js` file currently looks like this:

```
describe('myApp', function() {

    /*----- Global variables used for executing test scripts -----*/
    var username = "abc";
    var password = "xyz";

    var loginForm = element(by.id('loginForm')); 
    var loginBtn = element.all(by.css('.form-control > input[type=submit]')).get(0);
    var usernameInputField = element(by.name('inputName'));
    var passwordInputField = element(by.name('inputPass'));

    var navMenu = element(by.id('nav-container'));
    var pagesMenuBtn = element(by.id('.nav-container > model[type=href] > value["#/pages"]'));
    /*----- End of Global variables -----*/

    /*----- Global functions required for use within test scripts -----*/

    /*Define a function to log in to myApp automatically */
    function loginAsUser(username, password) {
        usernameInputField.sendKeys(username);
        passwordInputField.sendKeys(password);
        loginBtn.click();
    }

    /*----- End of Global functions -----*/

    /*----- TESTS -----*/
    //Test to get app title:
    it('should hit the VM hosted site', function() {
        browser.get('ip address');
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('myApp');
    });

    // Debug the tests using browser.pause(); 
    browser.pause();

    /*Test to log in- call 'loginAsUser()' from within test */
    it('should log the user in to Ultimetrics', function() {
        loginAsUser(username, password);
    });

    /*Tests for Navigation Bar */
    it('should display the Pages menu', function() {
        //Write test for testing mouseover menu element here
        browser.actions().
            pagesMenuButton.mouseEnter().
            perform();
        expect(browser.menu.pages.isDisplayed().toBeTruthy());
    });

    browser.pause();

    /*----- END OF TESTS -----*/
});
```

When I currently run my tests using the command `protractor conf.js`, as the script runs through, it opens a browser window at the address of my application, enters the username & password into the login form, and clicks the login button to log in to the site (i.e my 'login' test is executing successfully).

The next thing I see in the console is:

> Failures:
>
> 1) MyApp should display the Pages menu
>
> > Message:
> >
> > > Failed: Cannot read property 'mouseEnter' of undefined

This error is complaining about the line:

```
pagesMenuBtn.mouseEnter().
```

and appears to think that `pagesMenuBtn` is undefined, but I have defined it as a global variable at the top of my `spec.js` file:

```
var pagesMenuBtn = element(by.id('.nav-container > model[type=href] > value["#/pages"]'));
```

I suspect there's something I'm doing wrong with how I'm trying to use the `mouseEnter` function on the menu button to test that the sub-menu is displayed when the cursor hovers over the menu button, but I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here...

Can anyone explain to me how I would test that the correct sub-menu is shown when the cursor hovers over the relevant menu item?

**Edit**

I've looked into this a bit more, and am wondering if the issue is to do with the HTML that I'm using to display the menu? The menu is displayed (vertically, on the left hand side of each page) as a 'navigation' bar, when the user hovers over any of the buttons on the page, the 'pointer' changes to a 'cursor', and if there are 'sub-pages' within the menu item they're currently hovering over, the 'sub-menu' is displayed to the right of the 'navigation bar'.

I've now changed the test for displaying the navigation bar's sub-menu to:

```
it('should display the Pages menu', function() {
    browser.actions().mouseMove(pagesMenuBtn).perform();
    expect(browser.navMenu.pages.isDisplayed().toBeTruthy());

    browser.actions().mouseMove(!pagesMenuBtn).perform();
    expect(browser.navMenu.pages.isDisplayed().toBeFalsy());
});
```

and am getting the 'Failed test' error:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'pages' of undefined

The structure of the HTML for the navigation bar is:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper" data-ng-controller = "NavCtrol">
    <ul id="nav"
        class="nav"
        ...
        <li data-ng-mouseenter="setMenuTop($event)" ng-show="menu.pages.length > 0 || menu.upages.lenth > 0 || canCreatePage">
            <a href="#/pages" ... ><i class="..."></i><span ... ></span></a>
            <ul> class="text-capitalize">
                <li ng-repeat="page in menu.pages"><a href="#/{{page.location}}" target="_self"><i class="..."></i><span data-i18n="{{page.title}}"></span></a></li>
                ...
                // Several line like above- one for each 'sub page'
                ...
            ...
        </li>
        <li><a href="#/alarms" ... ></li>
        <li><a href="#/charts" ... ></li>
        // etc
    </ul>
</div>
```

The line from the test that is causing the error to be displayed is:

```
expect(browser.navMenu.pages.isDisplayed().toBeTruthy());
```

but `navMenu` is clearly defined, as I have defined it at the top of the file with:

```
var navMenu = element(by.id('nav-container'));
```

So I don't understand why I'm getting this error... Anyone have any suggestions?

**Further Edit**

So I've seemingly managed to resolve the error that said:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'pages' of undefined

by actually getting one of the pages that belongs to the sub-menu, and setting a variable to that value:

```
var pageSubPage1 = element(by.id('.nav-container > model[type=href] > ["#/pages/subPage1"]'));
```

then performing the `expect` on that particular variable:

```
it('should display the Pages menu', function() {
    browser.action().mouseMove(pagesMenuBtn).perform();
    expect(pageSubPage1.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

When I now run `protractor conf.js`, and run through my test script up to this point, I no longer get the message stating that it `can't read property 'pages' of undefined`, but now get one that says:

> Failed: location.getId is not a function

This error is coming from the filepath: C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\actions.js:151:44

which is the line:

```
cmd.setParameter('element', location.getId());
```

in:

```
  mouseMove(location, opt_offset) {
    let cmd = new command.Command(command.Name.MOVE_TO);

    if (typeof location.x === 'number') {
      setOffset(/** @type {{x: number, y: number}} */(location));
    } else {
      cmd.setParameter('element', location.getId());
      if (opt_offset) {
        setOffset(opt_offset);
      }
    }

    this.schedule_('mouseMove', cmd);
    return this;

    /** @param {{x: number, y: number}} offset The offset to use. */
    function setOffset(offset) {
      cmd.setParameter('xoffset', offset.x || 0);
      cmd.setParameter('yoffset', offset.y || 0);
    }
  }
```

which has come from the Protractor library, and is not something I have changed at all... so I have no idea why I'm getting this error... Obviously I can't make any changes to the library, so can anyone point out how I'm using it incorrectly, as it seems that this must be the cause of the error I'm getting?

Comment: first, you are closing your `expect` statement in the wrong place.  should be this `expect(browser.navMenu.pages.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();`  Second, what is `pages` here?  third, why are you calling `browser.navMenu`?  You have defined `navMenu` has a variable, so just call that... it wouldnt be part of the `browser` variable.

Comment: Oh yeah- missed that I was closing the `expect` statement in the wrong place, cheers. `pages` here is a list of 'sub-pages' that belong to that particular menu item. The menu item itself links to a 'parent' page, but when the cursor hovers over it, a sub-menu is displayed, showing the 'child' pages of that particular page. For example, if the menu item was 'Vehicle', the sub-menu would show menu items for 'car', 'boat', 'bicycle', etc. I have shown the structure for the HTML at the end of my post- `pages` is a `href` as defined in that, and has some `<li>` tags nested inside it- I'll add those

Comment: I've edited the HTML in my OP to hopefully show what `pages` is more clearly.

Comment: ok but in your test, how are you defining `pages`?  It looks like you have it set as a property of the `navMenu` that you defined, but I dont see that declaration anywhere.

Comment: Good shout- I wasn't... But I've just added the line: `var pages = element(by.id('menu.pages'));` to the 'global variables' section of my test script, and now get the error: `cannot read property 'isDisplayed' of undefined on the line `expect(navMenu.pages.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();`, so it just seems to have moved the error on to the `pages` element. Any thoughts why this is?

Comment: So I managed to resolve that issue by creating a new variable, and setting it to one of the 'sub-menu' items that I was expecting to see when hovering over one of the 'root' menu items: `var pageSubPage = element(by.id('.nav-container > model[type=href] > value["#/pages/subPage"]'));`, and setting my `expect` statement to expect this variable: `expect(pageSubPage.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();`, however, I'm now getting an error that says: `Failed: location.getId is not a function`, and it says that this happening at "ActionSequence.mouseMove`, which is not something I have changed...

Comment: you are calling `by.id` but you are providing classes and other HTML attributes, cant do that.  either use `by.css` or [another locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy) that best fits this HTML